# Android, How to define a parameter in arrayAdapter class

Tags: android, adapter

This is a simple question, I have an independent class for adapting my listView and I want set a parameter in this class, in my Activity that is adapting it's list inside:

`PageItemsInflater.java` :

```
public class PageItemsInflater extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

int _TYPE = 1; //this parameter

TextView tvno, tvcount, tvPrice;
Context c;

public PageItemsInflater(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = new LayoutInflater(c) {
        @Override
        public LayoutInflater cloneInContext(Context newContext) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages_items_list, null);
    tvno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no);
    tvcount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_count);
    if(_TYPE == 1){
        //TODO
    }else{
        //TODO
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

The parameter I said is **`_TYPE`** that in my `FirstActivity` I want set the **`_TYPE = 1`**, I mean I want change the `_TYPE` in my activities to set a special text for each activity. And in Activity I call my Adapter like this:

```
lv.setAdapter(new PageItemsInflater(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.pages_items_list, R.id.tv_no, names));
```

I don't want use **`SharedPreferences`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the constructor and pass the TYPE into the adapter.

```
public PageItemsInflater(Context context, int resource,
    int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects, int type) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    //do something with the type
}
```

Then initialize the inflater by yourself. If you want to have more flexibility, switch the BaseAdapter for even more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the constructor of your adapter class like this

```
public PageItemsInflater(Context context, int resource,
      int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects, int type) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}
```

And then set this Adapter to the list view like this

```
lv.setAdapter(new PageItemsInflater(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.pages_items_list,   R.id.tv_no, names,-1));
```